# "Password confirmation" message not showing up when both password fields are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working through the railstutorial.org . Currently on the Update Profile page part of it. When leaving the `Password` and `Password Confirmation` fields empty, only the `Password is too short` error comes up, though in the tutorial screenshot `Password confirmation can't be blank` message is present. But, it does show up when the `Password` field is filled and `Password Confirmation` field is left empty.

`edit.html.erb` :

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>                                     

<div class="row">  
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

`users_controller.rb`:

```
.
.
.
  def edit 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params 
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
.
.
.
```

`user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, 
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  before_create :create_remember_token

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

Comment: What does your User model look like? That's where you specify what to validate.

Comment: @SunilD. Added! I didn't think it would have helped, because I have not touched it for a few chapters and the message at least shows up when the Password field is filled with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User.rb` model is out of sync with the one [MHartl uses at that point in the tutorial](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/updating-users/app/models/user.rb).  Specifically, notice that he has an explicit `validates :password_confirmation, presence: true` in addition to the `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }`.  When you call @user.update_attributes, it hits these validators and, in his case, both fail, whereas in your User.rb model there is not the presence validator.

When you have the password field filled in, you're hitting validators defined in `has_secure_password` rather than in your model, which is why they appear then.

Comment: aha! I saw other questions on similar issue on SO and searched up and down the course for any mention of adding `:password_confirmation` to the `user.rb` file like it was done in other examples and couldn't find anything. Good to know you can compare the final code at the end of each push on github and thank you for the clarification on `has_secure_password` validation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the password and password_confirmation in your allowed parameters in you controller:

```
  private

  def user_params
    params.required(:user).permit(:name, :email, password,:password_confirmation)
  end
```

**EDIT:**

As the other had already pointed out you miss the validation of `password_confirmation`

```
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

Comment: Question says `“Password confirmation” message not showing up when both password fields are empty` and this doesn't solve the problem. Problem is related to model not strong params

Comment: @PauloFigaldo yep, I already have all that exactly as you suggested